# Crear una ListView y DetailView con dos modelos

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls

Tengo 2 modelos que estan relacionados con un `OneToOneField`, pero no sé como acceder a los 2 modelos, mi vista es la siguiente:

```
class ListaSolicitudes(ListView):
    model = Modelo1 #aqui recibe un solo modelo, como uso el segundo modelos
    template_name = 'listar.html'

class DetalleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'detalles_solicitud.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         context = super(DetalleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['modelo1'] = Modelo1.objects.get(id=int('pk'))
         context['modelo1'] = Modelo2.objects.get(id=int('pk'))
         return context
```

Al querer entrar a esta URL, me marca error:

```
ValueError at /registrar/detalle/1/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'
```

Ya probé con `string` e `int`, pero me marca error al hacer `QuerySet`, mis URLs son:

```
app_name = "agregar"

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'nuevo1/$', views.Model1CreateView.as_view(), name='formulario1'),
    url(r'nuevo2/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.Model2CreateView.as_view(), name='formulario2'),
    url(r'detalle/(?P<pk>\d+)/$', views.DetalleView.as_view(), name='detalles')
]
```

Y en mi template mando llamar los datos así:

```
Tu nombre: {{ Modelo1.nombre }}
Tus apellidos: {{ Modelo1.apellidos }}

Tu CURP: {{ Modelo2.curp }}
tu Nacionalidad: {{ Modelo2.nacionalidad }}
```

### Agrego mis modelos

```
class Modelo1(models.Model):
    nombre = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    apellidos = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return u"Número de solicitud: %s" % self.id

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return u'/registrar/nuevo2/'


 class Modelo2(models.Model):
    relacionModelo1 = models.OneToOneField(Modelo1, blank=False, null=False, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    curp = models.CharField(max_length=18)
    nacionalidad = models.CharField(max_length=50)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return "CURP: %s" % self.curp
```

Comment: Hola, ¿cómo has definido tus modelos?

Comment: Ya agregué mis modelos, Modelo1 tiene como campos charField a ,  nombre y apellidos; mientras que Modelo2 tiene como charField a curp y nacionalidad y como OneToOneField a relacionModelo1 (es lo que une a los modelos, además de que tendrían el mismo numero de id y pk)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error principal, el que muestras en tu pregunta:

```
ValueError at /registrar/detalle/1/
invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'pk'
```

Se debe a que `int()` necesita un valor que pueda ser convertido a entero y 'pk' es un valor inválido. Si lo que quieres es usar el PK que le pasas a la vista eso lo tienes que hacer de la siguiente manera:

```
class DetalleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'detalles_solicitud.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # El pk que pasas a la URL
         pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
         context = super(DetalleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['modelo1'] = Modelo1.objects.get(pk=pk)
         context['modelo2'] = Modelo2.objects.get(pk=pk)
         return context
```

Ten en cuenta que el `pk` que se está usando no es el mismo para ambos modelos. ¿Es eso lo que quieres lograr?

### Actualización

Ahora que puedo ver tus modelos, lo que puedes hacer es usar la relación inversa desde `Modelo1` a `Modelo2`:

```
class DetalleView(TemplateView):
    template_name = 'detalles_solicitud.html'

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
         # Asumiendo que el PK que estás pasando es del Modelo1
         pk = self.kwargs.get('pk')
         context = super(DetalleView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
         context['modelo1'] = Modelo1.objects.get(pk=pk)
         return context
```

Y en el template:

```
Tu nombre: {{ modelo1.nombre }}
Tus apellidos: {{ modelo1.apellidos }}

Tu CURP: {{ modelo1.modelo2.curp }}
tu Nacionalidad: {{ modelo1.modelo2.nacionalidad }}
```

Comment: si, de la lista con todos los registros, pasar la pk cuando se acceda al detalle

Comment: @Kuroi mira mi actualización

Comment: Como está, puedo acceder a la vista, pero el template no me muestra ningún campo del registro, yo lo llame como  {{su modelo.campo}} por ejemplo, {{Modelo1.apellidos}}

Comment: @Kuroi el nombre que le estás pasando al `context` es `modelo1` y no `Modelo1`

Comment: Al primer modelo si puedo acceder, al segundo todavía no

Comment: @Kuroi es probable que para algunos casos no exista la relación

Comment: en efecto, borré la bd y cree un registro nuevo y ya pude acceder al contenido ¿Sería igual para la lista de registros?

Comment: @Kuroi pues depende de lo que estés mostrando

Comment: Me refiero a la parte de la vista, ListView tiene pagination y solo puedo asignar un modelo, si utilizo la vista de detalle ¿Podré acceder a los registros para verlos listados?

Comment: @Kuroi desde cualquier template, si tienes `modelo1` entonces puedes hacer `modelo1.modelo2.campo`. Si tienes `modelo2` entonces puedes hacer `modelo2.relacionModelo1.campo`.

Comment: Entiendo esa parte, muestro un modelo y puedo acceder a sus registros y si quiero ver lo demás que está en otros modelos, lo redirecciono con un botón "detalles"